# Add value of existing key to new one in c++ hashmaps

Tags: c++, hashmap, key

I wish to insert integer data in hash maps in C++ using integer keys only. The raw data I have will have many keys repeated.  I wish to insert a value in map if the key doesn't exist. However if key exists the old data and the new I wish to add should be added ( c= old value of key1+ new value of key1;  c should be inserted for key1). Currently it's being overwritten.

TO find whether a key exists or not in Map  I found to use this

if ( map.count("key")>0)
 { // got the key }.

But if I have to do this check before every insertion it will just increase the complexity of insertion to n^2. Is there a better method ?

Comment: *The C++ Programming Language* uses just `map[key] += value` to do this, without any prior checking. Seems like that should work for you as well.

Comment: could you write out some sudo code...  I'm having a hard time following your intent.  Sorry (here to help)

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use `unordered_map` or `unordered_multimap` from C++11 or use its `boost` counterpart??

And also you can do this as:

```
auto i = map.find( "key" );
if( i == map.end() ) {insert into map}
i->second = new value;
```

using this technique if value already exist in the map, you have no check. and also according to `map`( or even `unordered_map` ) `map["key"]` will create item if it does not exist and default initialize it!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Lets say, you have a *map named* `m`, with **integer** `b` as value and `s` (can be of any data type, doesn't matter) as **key**, then you can use following snippet(C++):

auto i=m.find(s);              // iterator for map
if(i==m.end())             // element not found, if iterator reaches at end
    m.insert(make_pair(s,b));  // element inserted as new pair
else
{
    cin>>p;
    i->second+=p;          // accessing 'value' for given key and 
                           // incrementing it by p 
}
```